# Causal and Non-Causal PD Controller

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

Why is a Non-causal PD Controller:
$C(s) = K_ds + K_p$

When a causal PD Controller is:
$C(s) = (K_ds + K_p)/(\tau s + 1)$

The difference being the denominator. $\tau$ is the time constant and is "*sufficiently small and does not perturb the other poles substantially*".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because with the form:

$C(s) = K_ds + K_p$

you have a non-proper transfer function. In process engineering, you always need to have [proper transfer functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_transfer_function), where the degree of the numerator is less than or equal to the degree of the denominator.

A work around is to introduce an "approximate derivative", which is the second form:

$C(s) = (K_ds + K_p)/(\tau s + 1)$

if $\tau$ becomes too large, it changes the dynamics of the transfer function significantly, and therefore the overall closed-loop response. This also helps reduce the amount of noise generated by the derivative term (acts as a low-pass filter, see [PID controllers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Noise_in_derivative) on Wikipedia).

In practice, however, derivative gains are rarely used, PI controllers being the preferred implementation.

The causality aspect is because in the non-causal PD controller, you have more zeroes than poles, see [this discussion](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10204/why-more-poles-than-zeroes).